# How to center li element within a segment control?

Tags: jquery, html, css, controls

So I've created a segment control in html:

```
<div id="jobboard-segment-control">
        <ul id="segmented-control" class="segmented-control">
            <li id="1"><a>1</a></li>
            <li id="2"><a>2</a></li>
            <li id="3"><a>3</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Now im trying to style it to where, when a user clicks on one of the segments, that segment changes color and also grows larger (height). Everything happens as i want so far except that the selected segment grows downward in height instead of growing evenly from the top and bottom. Is there a way to to have the segment grow evenly from the top and bottom? Or center it after it has grown in height?

here is the css:

```
.segmented-control {
background-color: #fff;
list-style-type: none;
width: 252px;
height: 26px;
margin-top: 8px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
display: table-row;
/*margin: 0 auto;*/

-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.segmented-control li {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #000;
float: left;
margin-left: 1px;
height: 26px;
}

.segmented-control li.selected {
    /*background-color: #27688e;*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid #579bc0;   
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#579bc0), color-stop(100%,#27688e));   
}
```

And here is the js for the click event. It just removes the selected class from the li's and adds it to the one that was clicked:

```
    $('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
```

Comment: You might want to add the js code for the onclick event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not missing something, you can simply apply `margin-top:-3px;`  (*added height/2*) for the selected class.

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $('li').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.segmented-control {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 252px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  display: table-row;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.segmented-control li {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 26px;
}
.segmented-control li.selected {
  margin-top: -3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #579bc0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #579bc0), color-stop(100%, #27688e));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jobboard-segment-control">
  <ul id="segmented-control" class="segmented-control">
    <li id="1"><a>1</a>

    </li>
    <li id="2"><a>2</a>

    </li>
    <li id="3"><a>3</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: (-_-)...I was pretty sure i had tried that with no luck, but it works.